# How to decide which moduli to check when solving a "polynomial" congruence?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

Consider the following problem:

> Find all integer solutions to $y^2 = x^5 - 4$.

The solution goes something like – check modulo 11, where $x^5 \equiv 0, \pm 1$, and then check cases to arrive at the conclusion that no solution exists. I thought about checking mod 11 as from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we get $x^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$, but it was really a lucky guess.

My question is: how can one decide which moduli to check when one has to face a "polynomial" congruence?

Comment: Well, $x^5\equiv 0,\pm 1 \pmod {11}$. not just $+1$.

Comment: There isn't a general rule, but we often start with checking $8$. That doesn't help here, so we have to try other things.

Comment: Since you have a 5th power, for which you want to check as few cases as possible, it is often preferable to choose an n such that $5|\phi(n)$ (11 is indeed the smallest such n).

Answer (score 2):

You should check modulo $p=\text{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)+1$, if it is prime (here $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are the degrees of the variables). The reason this may easily work is: by FLT (if $p\nmid x$) $$x^{\text{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)}\equiv 1\pmod {\!p}$$

and $a_ik_i=\text{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ for some small $k_i$ ($\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$)(I say 'small' because we're taking $\text{lcm}$ as opposed to, e.g., outright multiplying them all).

$(x^{a_i})^{k_i}\equiv 1\pmod{\!p}$ has at most $k_i$ solutions in terms of $x^{a_i}$ (see Theorem below). $k_i$ is small, so $x^{a_i}$ can only gain a small amount ($\le k_i+1$ when $p\nmid x$ constraint is removed) of remainders $\bmod p$.

**Theorem:** a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ zeroes $\bmod p$.

**Proof:** $ax\equiv b\pmod {\!p}$ has one solution. Assume that any polynomial of degree $n-1$ has at most $n-1$ roots. Consider an arbitrary polynomial $f$ of degree $n$. If it has no zeroes, we're done. Otherwise (let the root be $a$) we can write $f$ as $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$, where $g$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. $f$ then must have at most $1+(n-1)=n$ zeroes. $\ \ \ \square$

**Example:** (Baltic Way 2012) Solve in integers: $2x^6+y^7=11$.

**Solution:** $2x^6\equiv\{2,8,22,27,32,39,42\}$ ([WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sort%5BMap%5BMod%5B2%23%5E6%2C43%5D%26%2C+Range%5B42%5D%5D%5D)), $y^7\equiv\{1,6,7,36,37,42\} \pmod{\!43}$ ([WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sort%5BMap%5BMod%5B%23%5E7%2C43%5D%26%2C+Range%5B42%5D%5D%5D)).

So $2x^6+y^7\not\equiv 11\pmod {\!43}$, and equality can't be satisfied.$\ \ \ \square$

Comment: how did you calculate the remainders of $y^7 $ and $x^6$ modulo 43 ?
I get that it $x^{42} \equiv 1 \mod 43$ but after that  ?

Comment: @LucyferZedd Since $x^6\equiv (-x)^6$, you can check only $x\equiv 0,1,2,\ldots, 21$. You check all of $y\equiv 0,1,2,\ldots, 21$ for $y^7$ and, since $(-y)^7\equiv -y^7$, you put a minus sign on all of them to find the rest. I'm not aware of any simple methods of finding them other than the brute force method shown. I used WolframAlpha here to find them (and left links in parantheses).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that by the Legendre symbol properties we have
$$
\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv x \pmod p
$$
where $x$ can be only $-1$,$0$ or $1$. That's why if you have a $n$-th power in a diophantine equation and $2n+1$ is prime, then you're really lucky, although it is not a strange guess xd

Comment: You don't need to invoke quadratic residues here: If $2n+1$ is prime, then $a\not\equiv 0\,\stackrel{\text{FLT}}\Rightarrow\, (a^{n})^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^n\equiv \pm 1\!$ mod $2n+1$ (since $p\mid m^2-n^2\,\Rightarrow\, (p\mid m-n\text{ or }p\mid m+n)$, so $m^2\equiv n^2\,\Rightarrow\, m\equiv \pm n\!\pmod{\! p}$). So $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \{\pm 1,0\}\!\pmod {\! p}$.